# Android - R.array.[variable] in a For loop?

Tags: android, arrays, string, loops

I'm looking for option to access array of strings defined in strings.xml in loop.
Means,  I have in my strings.xml -  several arrays like:

```
<string-array name="ques1">
    <item>bla bla</item> 
    <item>bla bla</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="ques2">
    <item>bla bla</item> 
    <item>bla bla</item>
</string-array>
```

How can i access in my code - the arrays of ques1, ques2...etc ?  (for example - i have many questions in my application with its answers, so i want to access it in generic way).

Answer (score 6):

```
String[] stringArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ques1);
for(String s : stringArray) {
     //do something with s
}
```

Edit ... I just realized you want to iterate not over the array, but over several arrays. That's also possible, with :

```
for(int i = 0; i<max_arrays; i++) {

    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("ques"+i, "array", 
    context.getPackageName());

    String[] stringArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(id);

    for(String s : stringArray) {
         //do something with s
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect!  this is exactly what i needed - Iteration over the arrays themselves. thank you very much.